# How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, duplicates, distinct

I need to retrieve all rows from a table where 2 columns combined are all different. So I want all the sales that do not have any other sales that happened on the same day for the same price. The sales that are unique based on day and price will get updated to an active status.

So I'm thinking:

```
UPDATE sales
SET status = 'ACTIVE'
WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT (saleprice, saledate), id, count(id)
             FROM sales
             HAVING count = 1)
```

But my brain hurts going any farther than that.

Answer (score 624, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c FROM t
```

is *roughly* equivalent to:

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM t GROUP BY a,b,c
```

It's a good idea to get used to the GROUP BY syntax, as it's more powerful.

For your query, I'd do it like this:

```
UPDATE sales
SET status='ACTIVE'
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM sales S
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT saleprice, saledate
        FROM sales
        GROUP BY saleprice, saledate
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 
    ) T
    ON S.saleprice=T.saleprice AND s.saledate=T.saledate
 )
```

Comment: This query, while correct and being accepted for year now, is **extremely inefficient** and unnecessarily so. Don't use this. I provided an alternative and some explanation in another answer.

Comment: isn't SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c FROM t *precisely* the same thing as SELECT a,b,c FROM t GROUP BY a,b,c?

Comment: @famargar for the simple case, yet, but they have different meanings semantically, and they are different in terms of what you can do for the step when building a larger query. Plus, people on tech forums can often be _extremely_ pedantic about things, I find it often useful to add weasel words to my posts in this context.

Answer (score 426):

If you put together the answers so far, clean up and improve, you would arrive at this superior query:

```sql
UPDATE sales
SET    status = 'ACTIVE'
WHERE  (saleprice, saledate) IN (
    SELECT saleprice, saledate
    FROM   sales
    GROUP  BY saleprice, saledate
    HAVING count(*) = 1 
    );
```

Which is *much* faster than either of them. Nukes the performance of the currently accepted answer by factor 10 - 15 (in my tests on PostgreSQL 8.4 and 9.1).

But this is still far from optimal. Use a [**`NOT EXISTS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) (anti-)semi-join for even better performance. `EXISTS` is standard SQL, has been around forever (at least since PostgreSQL 7.2, long before this question was asked) and fits the presented requirements perfectly:

```sql
UPDATE sales s
SET    status = 'ACTIVE'
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM sales s1                     -- SELECT list can be empty for EXISTS
   WHERE  s.saleprice = s1.saleprice
   AND    s.saledate  = s1.saledate
   AND    s.id <> s1.id                     -- except for row itself
   )
AND    s.status IS DISTINCT FROM 'ACTIVE';  -- avoid empty updates. see below
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=26c7eb96c3a22330a9c271d554c869fe)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6b5ef/1)</sub>

#### Unique key to identify row

If you don't have a primary or unique key for the table (`id` in the example), you can substitute with the system column `ctid` for the purpose of this query (but not for some other purposes):

```
   AND    s1.ctid <> s.ctid
```

<sub>Every table should have a primary key. Add one if you didn't have one, yet. I suggest a `serial` or an `IDENTITY` column in Postgres 10+.</sub>

Related:

- [In-order sequence generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500013/in-order-sequence-generation/17503095#17503095)
- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

#### How is this faster?

The subquery in the `EXISTS` anti-semi-join can stop evaluating as soon as the first dupe is found (no point in looking further). For a base table with few duplicates this is only mildly more efficient. With lots of duplicates this becomes *way* more efficient.

#### Exclude empty updates

For rows that already have `status = 'ACTIVE'` this update would not change anything, but still insert a new row version at full cost (minor exceptions apply). Normally, you do not want this. Add another `WHERE` condition like demonstrated above to avoid this and make it even faster:

If `status` is defined `NOT NULL`, you can simplify to:

```
AND status <> 'ACTIVE';
```

The data type of the column must support the `<>` operator. Some types like `json` don't. See:

- [How to query a json column for empty objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292575/how-to-query-a-json-column-for-empty-objects/24296054#24296054)

#### Subtle difference in NULL handling

This query (unlike the [currently accepted answer by Joel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54430/939860)) does not treat NULL values as equal. The following two rows for `(saleprice, saledate)` would qualify as "distinct" (though looking identical to the human eye):

```
(123, NULL)
(123, NULL)
```

Also passes in a unique index and almost anywhere else, since NULL values do not compare equal according to the SQL standard. See:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)

OTOH, `GROUP BY`, `DISTINCT` or `DISTINCT ON ()` treat NULL values as equal. Use an appropriate query style depending on what you want to achieve. You can still use this faster query with [`IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE) instead of `=` for any or all comparisons to make NULL compare equal. More:

- [How to delete duplicate rows without unique identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769454/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-without-unique-identifier/26773018#26773018)

If all columns being compared are defined `NOT NULL`, there is no room for disagreement.

Comment: Good answer. I'm a sql server guy, so the first suggestion of using a tuple with an IN ( ) check wouldn't occur to me. The not exists suggestion is usually gonna end up with the same execution plan in sql server as the inner join.

Comment: Nice. The explanation greatly increases the value of the answer. I'm almost tempted to run some tests with Oracle to see how the plans compare with Postgres and SQLServer.

Comment: `count(*)` is less efficient than something like: `count(saleprice)` (unless accuracy critical, then yes, use `count(*)` )

Comment: @alairock: Where did you get that? For Postgres, the *opposite* is true. While counting all rows, `count(*)` is *more* efficient than `count(<expression>)`. Just try it. Postgres has a faster implementation for this variant of the aggregate function. Maybe you are confusing Postgres with some other RDBMS?

Comment: @alairock: I happen to be co-author of that page and it doesn't say anything of the sort.

Comment: Why is here needed `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` at all?

Comment: @trthhrtz: Cause the OP is looking for unique combinations.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter , you are always so on point with your answers across the stack. You've helped throughout the years in a nearly unimaginable amount of ways. As for this example, I knew a few different ways to solve my problem, but I wanted to see that someone had tested the efficiency between the possibilities. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't the "optimal" version actually returning a wrong result? Because the "having" clause from the previous query is missing, the last one will eliminate all duplicate rows from the result set... Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Wecherowski: The query updates all rows where no duplicate exists - as requested. No `HAVING` clause, we are not aggregating anything to begin with.

Answer (score 28):

The problem with your query is that when using a GROUP BY clause (which you essentially do by using distinct) you can only use columns that you group by or aggregate functions. You cannot use the column id because there are potentially different values. In your case there is always only one value because of the HAVING clause, but most RDBMS are not smart enough to recognize that.

This should work however (and doesn't need a join):

```
UPDATE sales
SET status='ACTIVE'
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT MIN(id) FROM sales
  GROUP BY saleprice, saledate
  HAVING COUNT(id) = 1
)
```

You could also use MAX or AVG instead of MIN, it is only important to use a function that returns the value of the column if there is only one matching row.

Answer (score 7):

If your DBMS doesn't support distinct with multiple columns like this:

```
select distinct(col1, col2) from table
```

Multi select in general can be executed safely as follows:

```
select distinct * from (select col1, col2 from table ) as x
```

As this can work on most of the DBMS and this is expected to be faster than group by solution as you are avoiding the grouping functionality.

Comment: You still have duplicates. In my case, I have columns(id,col_a). Column col_a have duplicates, that I want to use distinct to remove duplicates. Using code SELECT DISTINCT(id,col_a) FROM Table will result:
"(2,2)"
"(3,3)"
"(4,3)"
"(5,4)"  as you can see, the second column has duplicates. I am searching for a solution.

Comment: I've found this solution:
`SELECT DISTINCT ON (col_a) id,col_a FROM Table`;

Answer (score 2):

I want to select the distinct values from one column 'GrondOfLucht' but they should be sorted in the order as given in the column 'sortering'. I cannot get the distinct values of just one column using

```
Select distinct GrondOfLucht,sortering
from CorWijzeVanAanleg
order by sortering
```

It will also give the column 'sortering' and because 'GrondOfLucht' AND 'sortering' is not unique, the result will be ALL rows.

use the GROUP to select the records of 'GrondOfLucht' in the order given by 'sortering

```
SELECT        GrondOfLucht
FROM            dbo.CorWijzeVanAanleg
GROUP BY GrondOfLucht, sortering
ORDER BY MIN(sortering)
```

Comment: This basically explains what the accepted answer does, but I'd recommend not using such names for an example (at least translate them). PS: I recommend always naming everything in English in all projects even if you're dutch.